# Should we change class component to functional component when we put state into Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was learning React and created two class components having respective states. Then, I learned about Redux and decided to transfer states into redux store. The question is "Is it best practice to change class componenents into functional components since we get state via props from redux store?"

Comment: First, you don't `get state via props`, it's an anti-pattern implement. Then, you can use both classical and functional components with Redux.

Answer (score 2):

Functional components with react hooks is the new standard of coding on React. For store management(f.e. redux) you may use as classes as functional components, but most of the libs moved to functional components and you may not use all benefits of last versions of them.

Why I prefer functional components and hooks over classes:

- Cleaner render tree. No wrapper components
- More flexible code. You
  can use useEffect on different state changes, in classes you have
  only componentDidUpdate for ANY state/props change
- You can define your custom hooks to keep your code clean and shiny

Answer (score 2):

1. IMHO, yes, I suggest that you should switch from class-based component to functional component as soon as possible.You might not want to know how the class-based components have bugged me so hurt before I decided to go with Hooks. The number of components in my large project is now over 400 (including both smart and dumb components) and keep increasing. Hooks keep my life easier to continue developing and maintaining.
2. Have a look at this useful article: https://blog.bitsrc.io/why-we-switched-to-react-hooks-48798c42c7f

Basically, this is how we manage state with class-based:

[image: Class-based component]

It can be simplified to half the lines of code, achieving the same results with functional component and `useState`, `useEffect`:

[image: Functional component]

3. Please also take a look at this super useful site: https://usehooks.com/

There are many useful custom hooks from the community that you can utilize. Below are the ones that I have been using all the time:

[useRouter](https://usehooks.com/useRouter/): Make your life easier with react-router. For example:

```
import { useRouter } from "./myCustomHooks";

const ShowMeTheLocation = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return <div>Show me my param: {router.match.params.myDesiredParam}</div>;
}
```

[useEventListener](https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/): simplify your event handler without using `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to subscribe/unsubscribe. For example, I have a button that needs to bind a keypress event:

```
import { useEventListener } from "./myCustomHooks";

const FunctionButton = () => {
  const keydownHandler = event => { // handle some keydown actions };
  const keyupHandler = event => { // handle some keyup actions };

  // just simple like this
  useEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler);
  useEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler);
}
```

[useAuth](https://usehooks.com/useAuth): authenticate your user.

```
import { useAuth } from "./use-auth.js";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  // Get auth state and re-render anytime it changes
  const auth = useAuth();
  // if user is authenticated, then show user email, else show Login
  return <div>{auth.user? auth.user.email: "Login"}</div>;
}
```

[useRequireAuth](https://usehooks.com/useRequireAuth/): handle redirect your user if they are signed out and trying to view a page that should require them to be authenticated. This is composed by `useRouter` and `useAuth` above.

```
import { useRequireAuth } from "./myCustomHooks";

// Dashboard is a page that need authentication to view
const Dashboard = () => {
  const isAuth = useRequireAuth();

  // If isAuth is null (still fetching data) 
  // or false (logged out, above hook will redirect)
  // then show loading indicator.
  if (isAuth) {
    return <div>Fetching data, please wait!</div>
  }

  // {...{ isAuth }} is similar to:
  // isAuth={isAuth}
  return <Dashboard {...{ isAuth }} />  
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of All, States can be used only in Class Component. In React's latest version there's a huge update that allows functional components to declare and use state using React-Hooks. So, the best practice I would personally suggest you is to use Class Component when you use the Redux Store. As you're a beginner, Please use a functional component where you don't use any state or props and just render DOM elements (**Note**: Functional components can accept props). Once you learn the differences properly, go with React-Hooks. 
I hope it helps!! Happy Coding!!

Comment: hi, so even if transfer local state into redux store, I should keep using class component Right? Also, Anglesvar, is it true that we have to totally switch to react hooks in 2020? Because I read in a certain article that doing async request in hooks is a bit unintuitive

Comment: It is up to FaceBook, the team decides what to deprecate. Before a couple of years, there was `componentwillMount` ,now it is an UNSAFE lifecycle method. React Hooks(useState) was not available till late 2019. So there will be updates and deprecations. That is why a developer has to go through Documentations released by the company itself to check for the updates. Let's wait for the official updates.